# Endomorphism of a finitely generated module and finite length of $\operatorname{Coker}f$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a noetherian ring $R$ and suppose that $\dim R≤1$. And let be a one to one homomorphism $f:M\to M$. It is true that $\operatorname{Coker}f$ has finite length as $R$-module?

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A finitely generated module over a noetherian ring is of finite length iff its support is contained into the maximal spectrum. (See [here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/ComAlg/ComAlg1.pdf), Proposition 1.6.9.)

Now let $\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Supp}(\operatorname{Coker}f)$. If $\mathfrak p$ is not maximal, then it is minimal since $\dim R\le 1$. But $(\operatorname{Coker}f)_{\mathfrak p}=\operatorname{Coker}f_{\mathfrak p}$, so the question can be viewed over $R_{\mathfrak p}$. But this is an artinian ring, and then $M_{\mathfrak p}$ is an artinian module, so $f_{\mathfrak p}$ is surjective (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273181/if-m-is-an-artinian-module-and-f-m-mapsto-m-is-an-injective-homomor)), that is, $\operatorname{Coker}f_{\mathfrak p}=0$, a contradiction.